# javascript prototypal inheritance and the 'new' keyword

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I've been playing around with prototypal inheritance in JavaScript and have been confused by the behavior of the `new` keyword. I cannot understand why the `[[prototype]]` property of the inheriting object points to `Function.prototype` and not the prototype of the inherited object. Consider 2 constructor functions (below):

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();
```

Querying the prototype of the constructor function `Cat`, I get some interesting results:

```
Cat.__proto__ === Animal.prototype; //returns false -- shouldn't this be true?
Cat.__proto__ === Function.prototype; //returns true
Cat.prototype instanceof Animal; //returns true, as expected
```

My understanding was that the `[[prototype]]` of `Cat` should be updated to point to `Animal.prototype` when we set it's prototype property to a new instance of `Animal`, which should in essence

1. create a new object based on `Animal.prototype` and
2. internally set `Cat.[[prototype]]` to `Animal`'s external prototype property?

I've tried this in both Chrome and FF with the same result. What gives?

Also, when we *assign* `Cat.prototype` to a `new Animal()`, what should `Cat.prototype` be? i.e.:

```
//if Cat.prototype = new Animal();
//then
Cat.prototype === Animal.prototype; //get false. Should this be true?
```

Comment: Use this - `Cat.prototype = Object.create( Animal.prototype );` - to set up the inheritance.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of `Object.create()` but the objective was to learn the 'barebones' approach to prototypal inheritance. `Object.create()` is the next step for me.

Comment: `X.prototype = new Y();` is flawed because the `prototype` object is polluted with the properties which are assigned to new instances of `Y`. You want to avoid this approach and do how it's supposed to be done (via `Object.create()`).

Comment: Also use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `.__proto__`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, could you elaborate on why it's flawed. I'm trying to understand the benefits of this approach. If you have any code examples, that would be great.

Comment: @keyser_sozay Inside the `Animal` constructor, you define a `name` property on the newly created instance. Therefore, all objects created via `new Animal()` will have a `name` property. In your code above, you assign such an object to `Cat.prototype`, which means that `Cat.prototype` will have a `name` property (inappropriately, since such a `name` property is only meant for instances of `Animal`). When you do `Object.create( Animal.prototype )`, you create an object which inherits from `Animal.prototype` (just like `new Animal()`), but this time, the newly created object is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cat.__proto__ === Animal.prototype; //returns false -- shouldn't this be true?
Cat.__proto__ === Function.prototype; //returns true
```

The `Cat` constructor is a function. Therefore, it inherits from `Function.prototype` which in turn inherits from `Object.prototype`. This is also true for the `Animal` constructor and all other function objects.

Just because you assigned to `Cat.prototype` doesn't change the inheritance link of the `Cat` constructor itself (inheritance links are immutable anyway).

Note that `Cat` instances don't inherit from `Cat`, but from `Cat.prototype`. So, you don't care about the prototype link of the `Cat` constructor anyway.

Comment: +1. To put it another way (maybe clearer, maybe not), instances inherit from their constructor's internal Prototype. Declared functions are instances of `Function` so they inherit from `Function.prototype` (as does `Cat`). Instances of `Cat` (i.e. objects created by `new Cat()`) will inherit from `Cat.prototype`, which in the example is a instance of `Animal`, so they also inherit from `Animal.prototype`.

Comment: So constructor functions and objects are different in the sense that constructor functions will always inherit from Function.prototype while object hierarchies can be different depending on the inheritance hierarchy of its parent during creation. But once declared/instantiated, the internal `[[prototype]]` hierarchy of both objects and constructors remains the same, i.e. immutable. Is this correct?

Comment: @keyser_sozay A few corrections: (1) Constructor functions *are* objects, too. So in your comparison, you probably meant function objects and non-function objects. (2) The inheritance link of an object always points to its constructor's prototype object (e.g. `new X()` objects inherit from `X.prototype`). *** Yes, once an object is created, it is not possible to change (redirect) its inheritance link.

Answer (score 0):

That the [[prototype]] property is owned by Object instead of by Constructor function.
So in your example,you will find that

```
Cat.prototype.__proto__ === Animal.prototype; //Return true
```

Common say

```
Instance.__proto__ === Constructor.prototype; //Retrun true
```

Cat is a Constructor function that is a instance of Function type,so you saw this result

```
Cat.__proto__ === Function.prototype; //Return true
```

My english is so terriable,but I wish that I have explained something. :-)